# Cloud Tasks is not available in the \"specified\" region

Tags: java, task-queue, google-apis-explorer

I am have a application running on app engine. There are 2 components one execute on App engine and another on Compute engine. They communicate via Task Queues. After Upgrading to version2 I am getting following error:

```
   {
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Cloud Tasks is not available in the \"us-central1-f\" region.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Cloud Tasks is not available in the \"us-central1-f\" region.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.ytg.infra.messaging.taskqueue_api.Quickstart.pullTask(Quickstart.java:147)
    at com.ytg.infra.messaging.taskqueue_api.Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:119)
```

Note: I have passed proper arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I was able to solve this on my own, Below I am providing its solution.

```
String queueNames = String.format("projects/%s/locations/%s/queues/%s", _projectName,_location, queueName);

              // Create the PullTasksRequest
              LeaseTasksRequest request = new LeaseTasksRequest().setMaxTasks(tasksBulkSize).setLeaseDuration(String.valueOf(leaseTimeInSecs)+"s").setResponseView("FULL");

              //Execute the request and return the pulled task
              LeaseTasksResponse response = _cloudTasksClient
                  .projects()
                  .locations()
                  .queues()
                  .tasks()
                  .lease(queueNames, request)
                  .execute();
              return response.getTasks();
```

This solved my problem. Sorry for late post.